# Problem with CiviRules 2.13 Field Value Comparison

Tags: civirules, issues, condition

I am running on CiviCRM 5.21.1, and have just upgraded CiviRules from 2.11 to 2.13.

I have several Rules which test for the Type of a Contact by using e.g. "Field Value Comparison  Contact.contact_type=Individual"

After the upgrade this rule does not fire, and the Condition appears on the Rules Management screen as "Field Value Comparison  Contact.contact_type=".  If I try to recreate the condition I get the same result, and I can see no other way of making this test.

I will have to stay on CiviRules 2.11 until this is fixed.

Tony

Comment: Is this just an example or is this actually the condition your are using? If so, have you tried the "Contact (Sub)Type" condition? Does that have the same problem?

Answer (score 4):

Try after applying patch from [here](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civirules/-/commit/2926012504e90b5f6ae65cf2ca60806289ebf682) on latest version of rules.

Comment: This is the correct answer BTW.

Answer (score 1):

I also raised this as a formal Issue and got the response here https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civirules/-/issues/70.  There is a fix, and the issue is now closed.